# How "this" reference is transferred in the following function

Tags: javascript, decorator

In the JS manual I have the following example, that is working correctly:

```
let worker = {
  someMethod() {
    return 1;
  },

  slow(x) {
    alert("Called with " + x);
    return x * this.someMethod(); // (*)
  }
};

function cachingDecorator(func) {
  let cache = new Map();
  return function(x) {
    if (cache.has(x)) {
      return cache.get(x);
    }
    let result = func.call(this, x); // теперь 'this' передаётся правильно
    cache.set(x, result);
    return result;
  };
}

worker.slow = cachingDecorator(worker.slow); // теперь сделаем её кеширующей

alert( worker.slow(2) ); // работает
alert( worker.slow(2) ); // работает, не вызывая первоначальную функцию (кешируется)
```

The question is: how the "this" reference is transferred into cachingDecorator function, if the cachingDecorator is not declared inside of the object, and is called like `worker.slow = cachingDecorator(worker.slow)`? I talk about this row inside the cachingDecorator: `let result = func.call(this, x)`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` reference is transferred in the last 2 rows when the decorator is actually used as `worker` object is before the dot.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` is not actually in `cachingDecorator`, but is rather in the anonymous function being returned. So the `this` value is not set until *that* function is invoked.

Because that function is assigned to `worker.slow`, and you're calling it from that object, the `this` value gets set to the `worker` object.

The important thing to remember is that `this` is kind of like a weird function parameter. It just has a keyword for a name and always gets set (except in arrow functions). It gets set based on *how* the function is invoked, instead of being set like regular parameters via arguments being passed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the function `cachingDecorator` returns a function declared like `function(x) {. . .}`. Any function like this will inherit context when it is invoked as a reference to an object member:

```
function magicFn() { return this }
const x = { magicFn };
const y = { someKey: 6, magicFn };
x.magicFn(); // === x, because it was invoked as x.magicFn
y.magicFn(); // === y
magicFn(); // === undefined, no `this` object member reference
```

So when `worker.slow = cachingDecorator(worker.slow)` is called, the resulting function invokes the original `worker.slow` using `worker.slow.call(this, x);` which proxies the incoming `this` value (in this case, `worker`).